# Pulling data from weird JSON array response

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am working with an API and the response comes back weird. I need to grab the ID field from the response below.

```
{
    "message_campaigns": [
        {
            "embedded_errors": [],
            "id": "2729",
            "is_legacy_message": false,
            "is_setup_complete": false,
            "message_campaign_type_id": 1,
            "name": "Message Campaign 1",
            "organization_id": 123
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is my attempt:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  // Seems like good practice
$responseData = json_decode($result, TRUE);
print_r($responseData);
```

I have tried several methods and cannot get it to work

```
$responseData[0]['id'];
$responseData->id;
```

I can't figure out how to get the `id` to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your curl_exec actually returns a response because you've set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

If I look at your json response you need:

```
$responseData['message_campaigns'][0]['id'];
```

Comment: Ok, this is the correct answer. But only because I hadn't included all of my curl_setopt values. I have returntransfer set to 0. Not sure why it was set that way, but changing it to 1 fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the result is an `array`, as you pass the second parameter as true to `json_decode`:

> [When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-parameters)

In JSON, `{}` stands for objects, and `[]` stands for array. You've converted all objects to associative arrays, so this'll work:

```
$responseData['message_campaigns'][0]['id']
```

Comment: the result is not an object. OP use associative array option.

Comment: `$responseData` returns an array, not an object.

Comment: You're right. Missed the `true` part in `json_decode()`. Edited answer.

Comment: wow really nitpicking when you have to downvote because of object/array in this

Answer (score 0):

You have the second parameter of [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) set to `true`, so an array (not an object) will be returned.

You'll also need to access `message_campaigns` as the first item in the array.

```
$responseData['message_campaigns'][0]['id'];
```

This can be tested:

```
$result = <<< EOT
{
    "message_campaigns": [
        {
            "embedded_errors": [],
            "id": "2729",
            "is_legacy_message": false,
            "is_setup_complete": false,
            "message_campaign_type_id": 1,
            "name": "Message Campaign 1",
            "organization_id": 123
        }
    ]
}
EOT;

$responseData = json_decode($result, TRUE);

echo $responseData['message_campaigns'][0]['id'];
// 2729
```

Comment: Looks like everyone basically gave the same answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work. And that's the weird part.  The OP cleaned up my returned Response but it doesn't actually return that way. It looks like this, and I wonder if thats an issue:  
{ "message_campaigns" : [{"embedded_errors":[],"id":"2741","is_legacy_message":false,"is_setup_complete":false,"message_campaign_type_id":1,"name":"KTVH-TV's Message Campaign 29","organization_id":307799,"send_to_existing_audience_members":false,"sending_status_type_id":0,"status_type_id":1}] }

Comment: It works for me (tested). Are you sure `$result` contains the JSON response you post at the top of your question?